# Creating an MVC Blog with a Rich Text Editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I know the basics of asp.net MVC, and want to create a nice little blog from scratch.  As for the blog portion, I need a rich text editor.  CKEditor looked good, but I'm curious as to how to save/retrieve rich text from a database.  It will be mostly images and text.  Is there an easy way to do this?  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks for the advice, I'll look into both answers.  But no matter what I choose, is there a simple way to store/retrieve rich text from SQL?  Again with mostly images and text throughout.

Comment: check the source code of open source projects like http://funnelweblog.com/ and orchard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are OK with TinyMCE, you can install it from nuget

```
PM> Install-Package TinyMCE
```

it will automatically create editor templates in your Views.

and in your model, just need:

```
[UIHint("TinyMCE_yourtemplatename"), AllowHtml]
public string Content { get; set; }
```

Comment: Here is an article with detailed instructions on using the various TinyMCE nuget packages.  http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/tinymce-html-text-editior-and-asp-net-mvc-setting-it-up-has-become-easy-with-nuget

Answer (score 2):

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) can easily be integrated with ASP.NET MVC.

You can integrate this with an `HtmlEditorFor` and post the values to the controller. (<s>Will post an example soon</s> [Article](http://quysnhat.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/using-fckeditor-in-asp-net-mvc-3/))

So say I have a formatted a text using this CkEditor

> This is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com). This is **bold**

So when posted back to the controller, the values recieved will be something like

```
This is a <a href="http:www.stackoverflow.com">link</a> . This is <b>bold</b>
```

and this value will be saved in database, so that covers the saving part.

Now to retrieve and display this formatted content, you can simply use `@Html.Raw()` and pass this content as parameter to this method, and the formatted text will appear.